# Check the existence of association combinations from a table

Tags: t-sql, associations, combinations

Folks, I am looking for the best way to retrieve following information.
I got a table with products and options assigned to them. Then I got a list of option combinations and wanting to know the existence of products for my combinations.

product to option table

1. p1 -    option1
2. p1 -    option2
3. p1 -    option3
4. p2 -    option2
5. p2 -    option3
6. p3 -    option3
7. p3 -    option4

My option combinations are [option1,option2], [option1,option4], [option2,option4] and [option3,option4]

My expected result is [option1,option2] and [option3,option4]

-The selection is based on, there should be at least one product associated with all the options in a combination. Here [option1, option2] is associated to p1 and [option3,option4] associated to p3. If the combination is distributed among multiple products then that combination will not be selected. Also there could be n number of options in a combination.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your example. Why is "[option1,option2] and [option3,option4]" the right answer?

Comment: Sorry. The selection is based on, there should be at least one product associated with all the options in a combination. Here [option1, option2] is associated to p1 and [option3,option4] associated to p3. If the combination is distributed among multiple products then that combination will not be selected. Also there could n number of items in a combination.

Comment: `select option from yourtable group by product` gets you most of the way there.